# Tensorflow: Installing from source - ImportError: No module named pywrap_tensorflow_internal

Tags: python, tensorflow

Using machine **Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS** and followed the steps defined in the documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources). I'm only building for CPU.

I've managed to follow all the steps successfully until I reach the section`Install the pip package` which states that:

```
Invoke pip install to install that pip package. The filename of the .whl file depends on your platform. For example, the following command will install the pip package

for TensorFlow 1.2.1 on Linux:

$ sudo pip install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-1.2.1-py2-none-any.whl
```

**Problem 1**: However, I've not been able to find any .whl file. Where can I find this file?

**Problem 2**: When I try to import tensorflow, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named pywrap_tensorflow_internal
```

**Problem 3**: If I try to import tensorflow from any other directory, I receive the error

```
ImportError: No module named tensorflow
```

It seems it can find the path to the tensorflow. How do i change that?

Comment: Problem 2 and 3 are natural when failing to build tensorflow from source. If building tensorflow failed, you will not find any generated .whl . Was your build successful ?

Comment: @ma3oun Yes, the last command I ran `bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package` ran successfully.

Comment: I think I missed the `--cxxopt="-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0"` flag for gcc versions greater than 5. Thanks.

Comment: You also need to run: bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/someTemDir ...and then install the generated *.whl in someTempDir

Answer (score 1):

It seems that some issues has happened in your `pip` that sometimes they are hard to find, because original `pip` is system-wide, which can cause some unexpected such as dependency issues, etc.

It is good idea to use [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads). It is a python data science platform. It can be deemed as a large py package extendable bundle with a python virtual environment tool called `conda`. You can create many isolated python environments with installing and updating py packages you need. Almost packages which can be found in PyPI using `pip` can also be found in Anaconda.

You can also use `pip` to install packages that anaconda do not contains for even `pip` is one package in it. All environments and packages are in your `/home/(..user..)`directory if you install without `sudo` as default.

For example (no worry about package dependancy):

```
[chain@ChainFedora Project]$ conda install tensorflow
Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: .

Package plan for installation in environment /home/chain/anaconda3:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

backports.weakref: 1.0rc1-py36_0
libprotobuf:       3.2.0-0
markdown:          2.6.8-py36_0
protobuf:          3.2.0-py36_0
tensorflow:        1.2.1-py36_0

Proceed ([y]/n)?
```

Very easy to get started with [conda cheat sheet](https://conda.io/docs/using/cheatsheet.html)